# How to escape or remove "\" from the gson generated string?

Tags: java, json, string, gson

I am loading a value from the property file and then passing it to gson method for converting it to final json object. However, the value coming from the property file has double quotes for which the gson is adding "\" to the output. I have scanned down the whole web but unable to find a solution

The property file contains

```
0110= This is a test for the renewal and the "Renewal no:"
```

Here's my code

```
public String toJSONString(Object object) {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    //Note object here is the value from the property file
    return gson.toJson(object);
}
```

This produces

```
"{ResponseCode:0110,ResponseText:This is a test for the renewal and the \"Renewal no:\"}"
```

I am not sure in the output, why it is adding or wrapping the \ around the literals or where ever we have the double quotes in the property file value?

Comment: Your output isn't actually JSON, just a string.

Comment: @cricket_007 It's a JSON string.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What I mean is that `ResponseCode`, for example, is a key, no? So, it should be quoted.

Comment: Please explain how you're calling `toJSONString`.

Comment: @cricket_007 I've removed my answer until they clarify, but the JSON produced is a valid JSON string. I don't want to guess what they pass into `toJSONString`.

Comment: gson method is returning as JSON string after taking in the property value based on the key and adding the \ for double quotes on the output is as   \"Renewal no.\"   instead of printing  "Renewal no."

Comment: That's not what needs clarification. What is the `object` you pass to the `toJSONString` method?

Comment: Object is a string object

Answer (score 5):

Based on comments on your question, the `object` parameter is actually referencing a Java `String` with the value

```
{ResponseCode:0110,ResponseText:This is a test for the renewal and the "Renewal no:"}
```

I can't say why, but that's what your `String` contains.

`String` is a special type which `Gson` interprets as a JSON string. Since `"` is a special character that must be escaped in JSON strings, that's what `Gson` does and produces the JSON string.

```
"{ResponseCode:0110,ResponseText:This is a test for the renewal and the \"Renewal no:\"}"
```

Comment: I tried to escaping by using string replace but no luck. The best only close solution i have is removing the double quotes itself but i guess that would be my last solution. I am looking for a way that instead of adding '\' for double quotes to  the output it should print as value with the quotes rather than \ (slash)

Comment: @MustafaFarooqui Why are you worried about the ``\``? That is valid JSON.

Comment: As per the requirement the output should be "Renewal no:" not this \"Renewal no:\ which has \ instead of quotes

Comment: @MustafaFarooqui That would be invalid JSON. If you're not trying to write JSON, don't use a JSON library. Instead, process the String yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The \ character is escaping special characters like " in the string. You can't store a " in a string without a leading . It has to be \".

You remove the slashes when you display any output string.

Apache Commons has a library for handling escaping and unescaping strings: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: i tried doing this response= oldResponse.replace("\\\"","\"") before passing it to the output to display but no luck  :(

Comment: It would be better to use a library like the Apache Commons String Escape utils, because it will be able to handle cases that your regex does not. These may for instance be other escaped characters or unicode.